# Can not get rid of HTML table border - with screenshot and jfFiddle

Tags: html, css, border, html-table, css-tables

Not a Drupal question, but probably a CSS/HTML question:

I have written a module for Drupal 7 with Bartik theme, which displays a button "Show". When clicked it will fetch JSON data from a PHP script and generate a HTML table as string and finally display that table inside (or instead?) of a `<div id="top"></div>`

This whole complex stuff (at least for me) works surprisingly fine:

[image]

However I have this minor cosmetic problem: I can not get rid of the fine white line between the tabel cells.

I've added `<table border="0" cellspacing="0"` inline - this doesn't help.

I've added an id to the table `<table id="last"` and CSS-code:

```
#last { 
    border:0;
    cell-spacing:0;
}
```

but this doesn't work either.

When I inspect in Mozilla Firebug or Chrome dev. console - [those attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuCbm.png) are there.

Also, I have a non-Drupal page too - it doesn't show those ugly lines.

Any ideas please?

I've read, there are CSS stylesheets, which supposedly reset everything, but they are probably overkill for my problem.

[My jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/afarber/3GGdP/19/) works too, but doesn't have the ugly white lines...

I'm not posting the URLs of the above mentioned pages, because they both are in Russian and require registration.

Comment: jsFiddle blocks ajax requests. Just hard-code some sample data for the demo.

Comment: Got my jsFiddle running, thank you: http://jsfiddle.net/afarber/3GGdP/19/ (it does not have the ugly white line though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be any code or URL that actually demonstrates the problem, but you could use the brute-force method of adding the following into the stylesheet:

```
td { border: none !important; }
```

It sounds like the problem is caused by some CSS code setting a border on the cells, overriding whatever you might set at the table level.

If this does not help, we at least know that the problem is caused by something else than the table and cell elements (perhaps some elements inside the cells?).

It it does help, inspect the `td` cells to see what is now causing the borders, and write a stylesheet that is sufficient to override that (or edit the settings that cause the borders).

Comment: That was it - thank you! `#last td { border: none; }` has fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

Try giving this:

```
table {border-collapse: separate;}
```

Comment: I've added that line to `#last` but it does not help

Comment: Else try `table {border-collapse: collapse;}`. Or make sure if that style is received by putting `table {display: none;}` and check for the table not to be rendered. :)

Comment: `#last {display-none;}` works (hides my table), but `border-collapse: collapse;` or `border-collapse: separate;` do nothing unfortunately